# delete sub-matrices within a large matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am generating a large matrix with all possible combinations of zeros and ones as follows:

```
X = dec2base(0:power(2,M*K)-1,2) - '0'; 
combinations = reshape(permute(X,[3 2 1]),M,K,[]);
```

in each matrix within `combinations`, I need to remove the ones that have more than one '1' in one or more of its columns.
For example:
If `combinations(:,:,j)` for any value of j is
 `combinations(:,:,j)=[1 0 0 0;1 0 0 1]` i.e it has two '1' values in its 1st column, i need to remove it using `combinations(:,:,j)=[]`, so, my question is how to test for my condition?

Comment: It's best not to generate the entire matrix in the first place. What is it you want to generate?

Comment: @knedlsepp, i want to generate a matrix that holds within all possible binary-elements matrices, that has no more than one '1' in any column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rephrase it: Find the matrices where `any` column `sum` is `>1` and delete them

In code:

```
logical_index=any(sum(combinations,1)>1,2)
combinations(:,:,logical_index)=[]
```

Answer (score 0):

As you explained you want to *generate a matrix that holds within all possible binary-elements matrices, that has no more than one '1' in any column*, building your matrix exactly is probably a lot faster than generating a matrix which is a much bigger and then do some pruning operations. (Yes, even though there are `for`-loops involved!)

**Version 1 - Loop `dim=3`, vectorize `dim=[1,2]`:**

```
%// Input
M = 7;
K = 3;
%// Computation
Vs = [zeros(M,1), eye(M)];
[numGrid{1:K}] = ndgrid(1:M+1);
Nums = reshape(cat(3, numGrid{:}), [], K);

combinations = zeros(M, K, size(Nums,1));
for i = 1:size(Nums,1)
    combinations(:,:,i) = Vs(:,Nums(i,:));
end
```

Or if you want an even faster approach:

**Version 2 - Loop `dim=[1,2]`, vectorize `dim=3`:**

```
%// Input
M = 7;
K = 3;
%// Computation
Vs = [zeros(M,1), eye(M)];
[numGrid{1:K}] = ndgrid(1:M+1);
Nums = reshape(cat(3, numGrid{:}), [], K);

combinations = zeros(M, K, size(Nums,1));
for i = 1:M
    for j = 1:K
        combinations(i,j,:) = Vs(i,Nums(:,j));
    end
end
```

**Version 3 - entirely vectorized using `bsxfun`**

```
%// Input
M = 7;
K = 3;
%// Computation
[numGrid{1:K}] = ndgrid(0:M);
Nums = reshape(cat(3, numGrid{:}), [], K);
combinations = bsxfun(@eq, (1:M).', permute(Nums,[3,2,1]));
```

For `M = 7` and `K = 3` all of these are at least 1000x faster than the original approach.

Comment: @AmiraAkra: Should work now. And this doesn't die the memory death for `M=8;K=3`.